# Could not find gem 'foreman-tasks (= 0.8.6)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, foreman, theforeman

I am getting below error when I am running Foreman 1.14 on my machine.

> usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:354:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'foreman-tasks (= 0.8.6)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide git repo for this gem in Gemfile like:

```
gem 'foreman-tasks', git: 'https://github.com/theforeman/foreman-tasks.git'
```

Comment: But I don't want to  install  foreman-tasks gem. It's installing on it's own. below is the error:
"There was an error while trying to load the gem 'foreman-tasks"'